# Gatsby load body data from json (file page-data.json) - not generate static html body

Tags: gatsby

I have problem - I have simple app written in Gatsby and I see my app works great but I have problem with generated html. My html have a static header and footer (html is static) but my body is generated from json data (fetched from page-data.json). This is not be problem for me but for SEO i big problem. Please tell me where is problem, what i must change on my code?

PS. I use mobx to manage state app on this site where data is fetched from json, but other site ex. home , about us has  generated properly